# Add a effect to jquery toggleclass()

Tags: jquery, html, css, toggleclass

I have read multiple questions about this but none actually got a answer that worked for me.

Im trying to add a effect like fadein/fadeout or slideup/sliddown to the toggleClass() feature from jquery but I can't figure out how. Does someone have a idea how to do this?

Adding:

```
transition: 1s;
```

To the class didnt work for me it just shows up instantly.

Class:

```
.hide{
    display: none;
    transition: 1s;
}
```

How can I solve this?

Thanks!

Comment: You can't transition a `display` property.

Comment: it removes the class hide if i toggle it this should transition slowly so the div shows up slowly

Comment: Doesn't matter..the `display` property is not animatable. You could fake it with opacity & visibility however - http://www.greywyvern.com/?post=337

Answer (score 1):

use this

```
toggleClass( class, [duration] )
```

Comment: Please edit your answer to add an explanation of how your code works and how it solves the OP's problem. Many SO posters are newbies and will not understand the code you have posted.

Comment: This link would definitely help you https://api.jqueryui.com/toggleClass/

Answer (score 1):

Since the `display` property has only 2 states you can't make a fading transition.

Try

```
.hide{
    opacity:0;
    transition: opacity 0.5s linear;
}

.show{
    opacity:1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

there is an option for this using jquery toggleClass()/slideToggle itself!!

**HTML**

```
<p class="targetid">test content</p>
<button>Click</button>
```

**Script**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("button").on("click", function () {
    $( ".targetid" ).slideToggle( "slow" );
});
```

});

[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3gLvumpe/)

Comment: Note that adding easing requires jQuery UI :)

Comment: or else update your script like "$( ".targetid" ).slideToggle( "slow" );"

Comment: Note: you can replace "slow" with time delay (ex: .slideToggle(1000))

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `display: none;` use `height: 0px;` then in the class you're toggleing put `height: __px;`.

Replace `__` with the height of the div. This will add a slide effect.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6usje2xq/)

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to compare `fadeOut/In` you would have to use an animatable property like opacity & visibility.

**HTML**

```
<button id="toggle">Show / Hide</button>
<div class="see-me show"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
#toggle {
  margin:25px;
}

.see-me  {
  width:150px;
  height:150px;
  background-color: #663399;
  margin: 25px;
  visibility:hidden;
  opacity:0;
  transition:visibility 0s linear 0.5s,opacity 0.5s linear;
}

.see-me.show {
  visibility:visible;
  opacity:1;
  transition-delay:0s;
}
```

**JQ**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#toggle').click(function() {
    $('.see-me').toggleClass('show');
  });
});
```

[**Codepen Demo**](http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/Ayhpg)